# ASP.NET page getting Windows Authentication Prompt

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

I have an asp.net **website** that uses C#.  It uses Forms Authentication for logging users in.  We recently switched hosting providers and moved from Windows Server 2000 to Windows Server 2012 R2, so IIS has changed considerably.  Since moving, the website works as expected with the exception for 1 area.  Whenever we try to access an .aspx page that's in a particular directory, we get prompted to enter our Windows Credentials.

[image]

This **only** happens in the "reports" directory.  We have other pages that are in other directories and we don't get the prompt when accessing those.

I made sure the "reports" directory had the same permissions as all other directories:

[image]

And I also made sure Anonymous and Forms Authentication was Enabled for the "reports" directory.

My web.config is very simple and looks like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="WebPortal.aspx" protection="All" timeout="50000000" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="WebPortal.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
<allow users="*"/>
```

Here is the Authentication options on the "Reports" folder:

[image]

I'd also like to note that the Windows Authentication feature isn't installed on this server:

[image]

Any help or guidance that can be given is appreciated.

Comment: Are you 100% Windows Authentication is not active on that folder on IIS?

Comment: I have Anonymous and Forms enabled while ASP.NET Impersonation and Basic Authentication disabled.  I don't see one for Windows Authentication.

Comment: Does your app pool identity has read access on reports directory and its children?

Comment: Yes...I've found the answer and am going to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After what seemed like endless Google searches on various keywords, I found this link http://forums.iis.net/t/1163972.aspx which held the answer.

In short, if the Report Services is installed on your server (in my case, it is), you cannot have a sub-folder called "Reports"...because then the server thinks it's a Reports Services folder, requiring windows credentials.  I renamed the folder and it works.